# Writing data to text files in series

Tags: python

I have a number of fields that need to be populated in order, as well as some of the fields need to be auto populated. When I populate the txt file, it all comes in as one long sting, but I need each row of code to represent each row of text.  Additionally, I cant seem to figure out how to get the "Market" and my Glob command to populate within the new text file.

```
market= ("Squds")

import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/Output")
file = open("testCF.txt","a")
file.write('"market":'[Market])
file.write('"vendor"')
file.write('"mileStoneUpdates":"N"')
file.write('"woName":' [(glob.glob("C:/Users/.txt"))])
file.write('"buildStage":"C"')
file.write('"designType":"Core"')
file.write('"woOverwrite":"Y"')



file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the newlines to the string (`\n`).

For the glob results I'm not sure what you want to do as you can use glob() to find files by expanding wilde cards, since you don't add any wildcards in "C:/Users/.txt" you could just add that without glob(). For market you want to concatentate it to the string that you are writing:

```
market= ("Squds")

import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/Output")
file = open("testCF.txt","a")
file.write('"market":'+market+'\n')
file.write('"vendor"\n')
file.write('"mileStoneUpdates":"N"\n')
file.write('"woName":"C:/Users/.txt"\n')
file.write('"buildStage":"C"\n')
file.write('"designType":"Core"\n')
file.write('"woOverwrite":"Y"\n')

file.close()
```

If you do have a glob.glob() results with multiple files, you can convert it to a string with join():

```
file.write('"woName":'+''.join(glob.glob("C:/Users/*.txt"))+'\n')
```